# Dependency not found in Python Wheel package in databricks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, databricks, python-wheel

I created a python wheel file containing two python files (file1.py and file2.py) that have some customized modules. file2.py has dependency on file1.py.

My local directory looks like this after creating the wheel file:

```
myfunc_wheel
├── build
|--myfunc.eg-info
└── myfuncpkg
     |_ __init__.py
     └── file1.py
     |__ file2.py
|__ dist
    |__myfunc-0.01-pu3-none-any.whl
|__ setup.py
```

file1.py:

```
def hello_world():
   print("hello world")
```

file2.py

```
import file1
#some functions
```

setup.py:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="myfunc",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="xxx",
    author_email="x",
    description="xxxx",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.7',
)
```

When I ran both of file1 and file2 locally, it didnt throw an error.

But after I installed the wheel file on a Databricks cluster and tried to import the modules in a Databricks notebook, it threw an error that file2 can't find file1.

```
from myfuncpkf import file1
from myfuncpkg import file2


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'
```

I have also tried putting the whole path to file1 but didn't work either.

How should i adjust my files to make the dependency work on Databricks?

Answer (score 0):

To make a directory a package, you need to have `__init__.py` in each folder. try placing an empty `__init__.py` file in your `myfuncpkg` directory. That should solve the problem. refer: https://realpython.com/lessons/package-initialization/

Comment: thanks for replying. I checked i actually have an __init__.py in myfuncpkg. And the dependency works in my local as well. But not sure why it doesnt work when i use it on databricks.